# Deploy to server with CircleCI and SCP

Tags: ssh, deployment, scp, circleci, sshpass

Say I have a repo that I'd like CircleCI to deploy after finishing the test sequence and the code is like so:

```
deployment:
      staging:
        branch: master
        commands: 
          - scp -r wp-content/plugins/timespan username@servername.provider.host:public_html/wp-content/plugins
```

That works locally because I've set up the authentication that's necessary. But with CircleCI, that context isn't there and so it prompts for a password which I can't enter by having it on the next line, i.e. `- passw0rd`.

So I've tried a couple other things without success: 1) adding an ssh key into Circle and it rejects that by saying they don't support encrypted keys. 2) I tried using sshpass but wasn't able to add it as a dependency because of not knowing how nor which package manager to use to get it in.

Perhaps someone can enlighten me? I don't think this is too far off but am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to encrypt the SSH key. 
I'm using CircleCi for the exact same thing, just add the uncrypted key to your SSH Permissions (you'll find it in your Project Settings on CircleCi in the "Permissions" section. Of course you will need the public key in your servers `authorized_keys`.

Otherwise you can add additional packages through your `circle.yml`: https://circleci.com/docs/installing-custom-software/

> You can use your circle.yml file to run arbitrary commands against your build environment. You have root access to your environment via sudo, so you should be able to customize it to your heart’s content!

Example:

```
dependencies: 
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ssh-pass
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! So my understanding of sshpass, et al. has evolved somewhat and I'm able to ssh into the terminal with `- sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@01-server.provider.host ` but now don't know how to run commands from there. Putting `git pull origin master` after that doesn't run. Thoughts? and the next level is stringing multiple commands together so that I can do a checkout, merge, and other git operations in one shot. Thanks!

Comment: I would use SSH keys. You want to run `git pull origin master` on the remote server? Jush using SSH (and SSH keys) you can do this: `ssh user@01-server.provider.host "git pull origin master"`. Or, if you have multiple commands to run, I'd put them all in a script on the remove host and then run the script using the SSH command.

Answer (score 1):

`sshpass` only needs to be installed on the client side. You do not need to install it on the server.

I am not familiar with CircleCI, but it sounds like you are trying to get it to install `sshpass` on the server, which is completely unnecessary. Just do `sshpass -ppassw0rd scp ...` in your CircleCI deployment script after having installed it on the server that runs CircleCI, and you should be fine.